# How to resize space of chart are and legend label

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I use ng2-chart in angular 2, how to resize spacte chart are and legend label ? Thank you very much.

**html**

```
<div align="center" style="width: auto; height: auto">
  <div class="chartArea">
    <canvas baseChart id="chartBalanceId" [data]="chartData"
            [labels]="chartLabels" 
            [colors]="chartColors"
            [options]="chartOptions"
            [chartType]="chartType"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

**component**

```
private chartData: number[] = [];
  private chartType: string = "doughnut";
  private chartOptions: any = {legend: {position: "right"}};
  private chartLabels: string[] = ["BTC", "ETH", "LTC", "XRP"];
  private chartData = [30, 34, 30, 6];
  private chartColors: any[] = [{ backgroundColor: ["#b8436d", "#00d9f9", "#a4c73c", "#a4add3"] }];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Elements will fill block size, so instead of using `style="width: auto; height: auto"`put them inside a div which has a fixed width.